# Display message

Tags: page-layout, pagemessages

I would like to display message with particular information in Salesforce.

I have created a custom field of type rich text and made it read only but it does not allow me to display the message I want.

Please see the screenshot what I want to achieve.

[image]

and please advise is this feasible and how to create such field containing message inside?

Regards,

Dilyan

Comment: Can you add some detail about when you want to show the message, eg is there a triggering action? You could this with a formula field or code but it depends on what you trying to achieve.

Comment: No, there is no trigger action. I merely want the following message "_Please type and enter the domains by separating them with a space (e.g "acme.com summit.com")_." to appear all the time above the Domain field. Could you please advise how to dislpay the message in the layout above the Domain field?

Comment: Couple of options, use a help hint on the field it self - if you need a more obvious message you could use a text formula with your message in there.

Comment: the text formula idea works great for the View page but won't appear on the New/Edit page. For New/Edit page - the only real solution besides hover help is VF -- or, have a good Validation Rule and the users will self-cure/self-learn by making mistakes and getting the error

Comment: Ok, but could you please advise and give an example how to create such validation rule and what to include in the validation rule in order to display the message I need?

Comment: Is this in a custom VisualForce page on a standard object layout page?

Comment: It is a custom VisualForce and I would like to know how to implement such page in my layout page? Could you please advise or include code example which can help me create the same or similar Visual Force page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called the [placeholder text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp). This is an attribute supported in HTML5, and you can set it in a VisualForce page via html passthrough.

There is an interesting answer here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hITqAAM

If this is a normal object layout, then we'll need to keep investigating :)